# Global variable in considered as null in Laravel, but correctly seen in normal PHP

Tags: php, laravel, function, global-variables

`pure-php.php`

```
<?php
`
$var = 'OK!';

function my_function()
{
    global $var;
    echo !is_null($var) ? $var : '$var is null';
}

my_function();
```

Result:

```
OK!
```

---

Now take a look at this:

`app/Helpers/global.php`

```
$var = 'OK!';

function myfunction() {
    global $var;

    echo !is_null($var) ? $var : '$var is null';
}
```

`composer.json`

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/global.php"
    ],
...
```

Then I did `composer dump-autoload`.

`app/routes/web.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    dump('before');

    myfunction();

    dump('after');
});
```

Result at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

```
before
$var is null
after
```

:-/

I'm wondering why we cannot get the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your laravel code it's in a PHP closure or anonymous functions, but in your `pure-php.php` it's just a normal PHP function. So in order to use the `$var` you need to do this:

```php
$var = 'OK!';

Route::get('/', function () use ($var) {
    echo !is_null($var) ? $var : '$var is null';
});
```

Second, it does not make any sense to me to have a global variable in the routes file and can be used everywhere. There are many better ways to have global variables if that's what you are asking for.

**Update**

This is the default behavior with Composer autoloading rather than Laravel. It has nothing to do with Laravel. Composer makes every effort not to pollute the global scope during autoloading. If you want to force global variables then you should declare them as global in your config file.

For example:

create `config/helper.php`

```php
<?php

return [
    'foo' => 'bar',
];
```

And then you should do this :

```php
function myfunction()
{
    return config('helper.foo');
}
```

Comment: I know that I can use `use` to inject the variable in `Route::get()` function, but I did it to make my question shorter. In fact the issue issue is in a helper file that holds some variables at the top and then defines some functions. Those functions cannot read the top variables even with `global $vars` at the top of the functions. The helper file located in `app/Helpers/global.php` and introduced in `composer.json` file. OK, to show you the real code, I will update my question. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Anyway, it shouldn't return `NULL` when I use `global $var;` even if there is a better way to introduce the `$var`, am I right?

Comment: Question updated. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Thank you, may I have the documentation link?

Comment: @MohammadNaji for laravel or for composer?

Comment: The document that states Composer keeps variables from being globally accessed, and the solution that you described.